# Kubernetes Dashboard an error on the server ("unknown") has prevented the request from succeeding

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-dashboard

After getting my k8s cluster up and going I faithfully deployed the following WebUI dashboard
using the command:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.4/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
```

When I try to access it I get the following error:

```
Metric client health check failed: an error on the server ("unknown") has prevented the request from succeeding (get services dashboard-metrics-scraper)
```

If I get all the services I get:

```
k get services --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE              NAME                        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
default                kubernetes                  ClusterIP   10.96.0.1     <none>        443/TCP         8d
kube-system            kube-dns                    ClusterIP   10.96.0.10    <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   8d
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper   ClusterIP   10.96.0.65    <none>        8000/TCP        6m10s
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard        ClusterIP   10.96.0.173   <none>        443/TCP         6m10s
```

Can someone shed some light? what am I missing?

More Info:
In the dashboard yaml I found these roles:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["secrets"]
    resourceNames: ["kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder", "kubernetes-dashboard-certs", "kubernetes-dashboard-csrf"]
    verbs: ["get", "update", "delete"]
   
 map.
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["configmaps"]
    resourceNames: ["kubernetes-dashboard-settings"]
    verbs: ["get", "update"]
    
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["services"]
    resourceNames: ["heapster", "dashboard-metrics-scraper"]
    verbs: ["proxy"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["services/proxy"]
    resourceNames: ["heapster", "http:heapster:", "https:heapster:", "dashboard-metrics-scraper", "http:dashboard-metrics-scraper"]
    verbs: ["get"]

    ---
    
    kind: ClusterRole
    apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
      name: kubernetes-dashboard
    rules:
      
      - apiGroups: ["metrics.k8s.io"]
        resources: ["pods", "nodes"]
        verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
    
    ---
    
    apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
    kind: RoleBinding
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
      name: kubernetes-dashboard
      namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
    roleRef:
      apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
      kind: Role
      name: kubernetes-dashboard
    subjects:
      - kind: ServiceAccount
        name: kubernetes-dashboard
        namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
    
    ---
    
    apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
    kind: ClusterRoleBinding
    metadata:
      name: kubernetes-dashboard
    roleRef:
      apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
      kind: ClusterRole
      name: kubernetes-dashboard
    subjects:
      - kind: ServiceAccount
        name: kubernetes-dashboard
        namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
```

Looks like the kubernetes-dashboard user has access to the metrics service I might be wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the kubernetes-dashboard's serviceaccount doesn't have access to all kubernetes resources (in particular, it can't access the metric server service).

To fix this you should create a new ServiceAccount for the dashboard and give it more permissions.

Here's one that I found on another similar post (**be careful since it will give admin privileges to the dashboard, and whoever uses it will be able to destroy/create new or existing resources on your kubernetes cluster**):

```
   apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
   name: kubernetes-dashboard
   labels:
       k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
roleRef:
   apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
   kind: ClusterRole
   name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kube-system
```

If you don't have a cluster-admin ServiceAccount, create one following this template:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: admin
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: Reconcile
```

Admin ClusterRole:

```
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1alpha1
metadata:
  name: admin
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["*"]
    resources: ["*"]
    verbs: ["*"]
    nonResourceURLs: ["*"]
```

Comment: I already have a service account called "kubernetes-dashboard", it is the ClusterRole with admin priviledge that I don't have, and I also created a certificate signed by cluster CA with the subject "/CN=kubernetes-dashboard" and loaded the .p12 file into the browser.

Comment: I just added the admin ClusterRole yaml to my answer.

Comment: well surely looks like I need to remove something: one of them The ClusterRole "admin" is invalid: rules[0].nonResourceURLs: Invalid value: []string{"*"}: rules cannot apply to both regular resources and non-resource URLs

Comment: I am not sure if its related but I just did kubectl top pod and got the following error: Error from server (ServiceUnavailable): the server is currently unable to handle the request (get pods.metrics.k8s.io) my metrics server isn't running, i pulled up the ClusterIP  (10.96.0.65) address of the metrics server and tried to ping it from the master or from any of the machines in the cluster I didn't get a reply:

Comment: Looks like you're having an issue with the metrics server itself, try redeploying it from the official repository.

Comment: yeah that is exactly what I did i redeployed and I cant ping any service ip from the machines on the cluster...could it be a problem?

Comment: I don't know how to help you without more information, try opening a new issue and close this one